# Could not find firebase-database-19.6.0.aar

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to install the firebase database for real time database in my project but im facing an exception every time I try to run.
here's the exception I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find firebase-database-19.6.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-database/19.6.0/firebase-database-19.6.0.aar
```

and here's the firebase database version along with the firebase core version in my pubspec:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
```

and here's my android/build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and these are my dependencies in my app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}
```

I've tried upgrading the gradle version along with the google service version to no avail I tried (flutter clean, deleting the project and coping everything to a new project) I've also tried installing this package in my other projects and it worked fine but it seems the issue is from something else in this project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the gradle version in the `gradle/wrapper` file was new and doesn't have this file (firebase-database-19.6.0.aar).

So this is what it was:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-all.zip
```

and this is it now:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```